# Servicem8 API Notes, Bulk "active" = 0,

Tags: json, servicem8

I am trying to mark all the notes made by a particular users uuid to 0 so they do not show, altho i am only able to do them one at a time.

When i post via rest for one line it works fine see image below
[one field update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip4Nz.png)

altho if i try multiple note uuid i get a ok responce but it wont update the fields see below

[multiple field updaes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2YUl.png)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ServiceM8 API doesn't support bulk/batch record updates, to update multiple records you will need to submit a request to the API for each record change required.